# Saving temporary (in memory b64 string) image to Django Imagefield

Tags: django, django-forms, webcam.js

I'm using [webcam.js](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) to capture user's image during user's registration on my template.

It prompts user permission and, if agreed, enable a "Take picture" button on page. On click, it takes a snapshot on the user's webcam. All working until saving the picture to django's ImageField.

Although it recommends using AJAX (which I can't understand in a million years) to upload it to my server, I've modified a little to pass the base64 string through an hidden input field. I've also managed to decode the base64 string and save it as a file '.jpeg' on the server successfully.
I wish to save it from the memory, without writing it to the disk.

On models.py, `foto` is the ImageField. I'm using Django 1.9.4 and Postgres 9.4

Enough talk, here's my coding attempt which saves everything but the image:

views.py

```
class view1(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
        form.foto = b64decode(request.POST['foto'][-(len(request.POST['foto']) - 24):])
        #decoding 'foto' received from POST, some stripping is needed
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect()
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect()
```

template

```
    <form>
            <input type='submit' value="Submit">
            <input type='hidden' id='foto' name='foto'> 
    </form>

  <!--- JS from webcam.js takes picture and pass b64 string to #foto--->
  <!--- document.getElementById('foto').value="'"+data_uri+"'"; added to function "take_snapshot" --->
```

Any suggestions on how to manage the b64 string on my view?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, 3 days without any comments or answers, I've accomplished an workaround on my problem:

*under the post method:*

```
            img_data = b64decode(request.POST['foto'][-(len(request.POST['foto']) - 24):])
            fh = open(PATH.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'img.jpeg'), 'w+b')
            fh.write(img_data)
            instance.foto = File(fh)
            instance.save()
            fh.close()
```

Some considerations are necessary though.
This **ain't a solution to write it directly from memory**, it solves my specific problem. It might solve yours, so I'm sharing.

The main two reasons I've wanted to save it directly from memory were:

1. To avoid unnecessary disk-readings, some may say they are SLOW
2. To avoid file duplication

Number 1 is still a problem. I'm considering number 2 as not a problem, although this code still keeps a duplicated copy of the last image saved as 'img.jpg'. Go ahead and delete it afterwards if you want.

Anyway, I'm keeping this question open in case someone finds (and share) a better solution.